# Difference between What are they doing? vs What they are doing?

Tags: grammaticality

> 1. what are they doing?
> 2. What they are doing?

What is the difference between these two? Both are correct?

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/correct-usage-of-verb-and-pronoun-in-the-sentence/3562#3562

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. correct syntax for a stand alone question. *What are they doing?*
2. incorrect or incomplete - *I know what they are doing* would be correct