# Usage of auxiliary verbs in "How ..." questions

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

I don't understand the usage of auxiliary verbs in questions that begin with *How* (*"How ...?"*), and always use structures such as:

> How to learn play piano?
>   How long it take to deliver product?

Do these questions require ***do/does*** or ***may/can***?
Where do we place them in our sentences, if they're necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions starting with "how", specifically, the ones you use as examples, require an auxiliary verb. It should be placed immediately after "how", followed by the subject, then the verb. Which auxiliary verb you need depends on two factors, namely:

- tense
- subject

Assuming you want to ask your first example in present tense, you should say

> How long **does it take** to learn to play the piano?

Maybe you can write your second example in the correct way as a comment to this answer.

Comment: I think that common sense question fine to be written in simple present tense, so I will use **do/does**. For another example I can't identify subject and don't understand word grouping: **how to** or **to learn** are related.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

After another round of search, I found similar questions:

- [Why do my "How to" questions often get renamed to "How do I"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20730/why-do-my-how-to-questions-often-get-renamed-to-how-do-i)
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189228/how-we-make-a-car-or-how-do-we-make-a-car
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56625/how-to-vs-how-do-i
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69769/the-subjective-filter-question-is-contributing-to-the-decline-of-the-english-lan

As *JMB* says in his answer, "how" questions require an "auxiliary verb" in front of the "subject" (the structure which I previously misunderstood):

> How do I ask ...?
>   How should I rewrite ...?
>   How can I negotiate ...?

To avoid using the pronoun *I* in these questions, it is possible to rephrase the questions like this:

> What is the way to ...?

or like this (asking *you* instead *I*):

> How would you make ...?
>   How do you make ...?

Comment: Good advice! I'd like to add another option: *How would you make ...?*; which is generally considered more polite than *How do you ...?*

Comment: Thanks for the links. ['How to' vs 'How do I'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56625/how-to-vs-how-do-i) is specially relevant for your _"How to learn play piano?"_