# What is the difference between "... when are you..." and "... when you are..." in a sentence?

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between these sentences?

> Please let me know **when you are** available for a meeting.

> Please let me know **when are you** available for a meeting.

Comment: The second is not in the normal form for a question. See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/why-are-you-you-are-making-noise?rq=1) and many other posts on the theme of word order in questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two examples are not questions.  They are statements, and hence there should be no inversion.

Only example 1 is right.

> Please let me know when **you are** available for a meeting.

We do subject-verb inversion when we ask certain questions:

> When **are you** available for a meeting?

We could use the above construction if we prefer the question form.

The statement *Please let me know when **you are** available for a meeting.* can have 2 interpretations. In oral form, the way we stress the **when** would determine whether we want the reply now or only when the date of meeting is decided.

In *Please let me know when you are available for a meeting.* if "when you are available for a meeting" is nominal, you are asking for a reply now. If "when you are available for a meeting" is adverbial, you are not asking for a reply now.

There are hence 2 possibilities.

In written form, context would determine the meaning.

Comment: I wanted to receive an exact time for a meeting. Can we understand first example as only should be answered when they are available and with an answer like "I am available now"?

Comment: In Seowjooheng's examples, the first means "Please tell me (now) when you will be available (in the future)" and the second "Please let me know (in the future) when you become available".